Counter-example to $f$ is $T$-invariant iff $f$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable?
I'm watching a video on The Ergodic Theorem and at around 9:33 he states that

$f$ is $T$-invariant iff $f$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable

$T$ is a measure preserving function on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $f$ is a measurable function. Here is my counter-example, can someone tell me if/where I'm going wrong?

$\Omega = {x_0, x_1}$
$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$
$\mu$ is the counting measure
$T(x_i) = f(x_i) = x_{1 - i}$ (they both swap the $x$'s).

So, $T$ is measure preserving and has $\mathcal{F}_T = \{ \emptyset, \Omega\}$ (which is a perfectly find $\sigma$-algebra)  and $f$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable since $f^{-1}(\Omega) = \Omega$ but it is not $\mathcal{F}_T$ invariant since
$$f \circ T \equiv Id \neq f.$$
Am I missing something?

Yes, you are not allowed to choose which $\sigma$-algebra to pick, at the destination. It should be the old one, not the one consisting of invariant measurable subsets.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928672/measurability-with-respect-to-the-sigma-algebra-of-invariant-sets for a more precise statement. Not that $f$ is moreover assumed to be real-valued.

Here $\mathcal F_T$-measurable means measurable as a map from $(\Omega,\mathcal F_T)$ to $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. So $f$ is not $\mathcal F_T$-measurable.
